# Is It Possible to assign authorization to views?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, view, authorization

I wish that in My site some users can see a view.
Are there more authorization options in addition to personal and public view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create multiple document libraries with different permissions on them, or use document level permissions. Just create the views in your regular list or library and move the resulting file(s) from the /Forms-directory to your secured document library. Your view will still list in the dropdowns to choose for on the list/library, but will use the permissions of the library it is actually in. 
Note though: your user still needs to be able to access the items that are in the list/library to be able to see them. This also works on files like DispForm.aspx by the way.
The only thing you're actually 'protecting' this way is the metadata/columns.

Comment: this works perfetctly. thx!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Audience Targeting along with a SharePoint Group.

First create a SharePoint group and add required users into it.

Then edit page, select list view webpart and choose properties. From the properties pane, select Audience and select the group created above.

Comment: This answer Partially to my question. To use this workaround You first have to put your list in a page as a webpart. Unlucky, Sharepoint online is not very user-friendly in configuring webpart's views...
I mean... By modifing a view in a list the webpart that point to that view never update until you do it manually.